# working with AccessibilityService, dispatchGesture always returns false

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

The most common answer is that you need to add android:canPerformGestures="true", but I already added it. Please help me understand this. I'm writing a program in flutter, and I'm trying to make gestures through the created plugin.
Permissions are granted and the onServiceConnected function is called.
Gesture code:

```
fun clickAt(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean {
        val gestureBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
        gestureBuilder.addStroke(GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 1L))
        val gesture: GestureDescription = gestureBuilder.build()



        return dispatchGesture(gesture, object : GestureResultCallback() {
            override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                Log.d("start", "+++++");
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)

            }

            override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription) {
                Log.d("start", "-----");
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)

            }
        }, null)
    }
```

Code added to manifest:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.macroexternal.macrodroid.accessibility_plugin.TextReaderAccessibilityService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>
```

Code added to a separate xml file accessibilityservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowsChanged|typeAllMask|typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:notificationTimeout="300"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.macroexternal.SettingsActivity"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    >
</accessibility-service>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing. dispatchGesture always returns false and the onCompleted and onCancelled functions are not called

I tried reading the documentation and asking about GPT, but couldn't find anything additional.

Comment: I've made some progress on the issue.
If I call the event in override fun onAccessibilityEvent
It works, but if I call it whenever I want in a separate function, and not on an event inside, then it does not work. Maybe it has something to do with it being in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was creating my own instance of the AccessibilityService class however the application creates this class itself as a service.